# CSS links don't work properly

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

the links in "request" div don't appear properly. For links in this div in style.css there is the following code:

```
.header .request a span{border-bottom:1px dotted}.header .request a:hover span{border-bottom:0}
```

Proof: berdyanskaya56.ru

On the page while link is hovered she becomes underlined. In comparison, in .css clearly stated that it should be none-decorated. How can I fix this?

UPD:
-> goal: make links in div "request" dotted-underlinead while unhovered and non-underliened while hovered. All attributes of style of the links should be written in .css rather than in html (don't write style="text-decoration:none" in index.html).

-> present situation: link is dotted-underlined, but it becomes underlined (___) instead of non-underlined while hovered.

Comment: you need to specify what you want to achieve here?? **if you are giving some URL link and expecting to check `request div` it is not at all possible**. Nobody will understand also at least i didn't understand what your saying??. Explanation will help in solving your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work fine. Just add

```
div.header div.request a {
    text-decoration: none;/*add this*/
}
```

```css
.header .request a span {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted
}
.header .request a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 0
}
div.header div.request a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="request">
    <a href="#">
      <span>sadsad</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Becausec you have another `<a>` tags in the project that have by default `a:hover{text-decoration:underline}`.

Add this css to your project:

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: It is a:hover. Edited my answer.

Comment: Try text-decoration:none!important; to see if you have a specificity problem.

Comment: Added a:hover instead of a:hover span - nothing fixed

Comment: Added text-decoration:none!important; - no way to work

Comment: You have in your project `a { text-decoration:none; color:#fff}`. Change this to `a:hover { text-decoration:none;}` `a{color:#fff}`. Don't do something like `.header .request a:hover {...}`, only select  all the `<a>` tags within your website.

Comment: Added. Still doesn't work (for proof visit the page).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style in your CSS.

```
 .header .request a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I found that If you add style="text-decoration:none;" to the link on the page, it fixes. My goal is to include this attribute in .css.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header .request a span {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

remove `border:0` here and add `text-decoration: none;`in this css

```
.header .request a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

on hover i am modifying the `border-bottom:none;`

```
.header .request span:hover{
    border-bottom:none;
    }
```

Upadte this css i hope it will fix your issue

Comment: Nothing fixed. Check it.

Comment: It's still underlined while hovered. I know, it's weird but it doesn't fix the issue. Visit and check it yourself.

Comment: Updated the css. It becomes both dotted-underlined and underlined while hovered.

Comment: I'm using cloud flare. Now I purged the cache.